# Set up dual independent monitors in Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display, display-manager

I have an nvidia quadro M2000 and Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Precision 3620 workstation. I need to run my two monitors separately. I can use the standard Ubuntu settings to extend my desktop onto the monitors, but I need the monitors to run separate desktops. How can I do this please?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Ubuntu's own help documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-dual-monitors.html)

- Open the Activities overview and start typing Displays.

  Click on Displays to open the panel.

  Click on the second monitor, then in the list of monitor configuration select Secondary to activate it.

  The primary monitor is the one with the top bar, and where the
  Activities overview is shown.

  To rotate the orientation of the monitor, use the buttons with the
  arrows until the preview is correct.

When you are happy with your settings, click Apply and then click Keep Changes.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue. Using Ubuntu 18.04.

To have each display behaving like a separate desktops/workspaces first go to **Settings > Dock** and select **All displays** option for **Show on**

Then install dconf-editor

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

and navigate to
**org > gnome > shell > extensions > dash-to-dock**
and check **isolate-monitors**