# Dual display with independent workspace sliding option, similar to mac

Tags: workspaces

With additional monitor on ubuntu 22.04 I'm looking to slide the workspaces independently similar to mac. If I have Workspace1 and Workspace2 on External Monitor and then Workspace3 and Workspace4 on Laptop Display. I'd like to just slide between Workspace3<-->Workspace4 on Laptop (and vice versa) and keep the Workspace1 and Workspace2 static on External Monitor... so Mac does it by tracking the mouse pointer location. If the pointer is on external display it would be just sliding that on Alt+Ctrl+(Right/Left) or 3 finger slide on touchpad.

Currently when I slide any of the workspaces all displays (External+Laptop Display) slide left/right together which doesn't give me flexibility to switch between workspaces independently on either displays.

I've already tried the below isolation with no luck :

[Set up dual independent monitors in Ubuntu 18](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057928/set-up-dual-independent-monitors-in-ubuntu-18)

Any help would be great ! Thanks in advance...

Comment: so that isolate windows configuration is more to control what the dock shows, sadly i have not found a way to have independent workspaces per monitor so far

Comment: thanks for that, I think upon further looking up and testing I noticed that if we highlight an APP on the laptop screen and press [SHIFT+Ctrl+Alt+Right/left] it shifts that App to right/left window without changing the External Display screen... which kinda gives me a way to sort my Apps/Workspaces....

Comment: is there any solution to that? except for this workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround : Highlight the App, then Use [SHIFT+Ctrl+Alt+Right/left] it shifts that App to right/left window on Laptop screen without changing the External Display Screen.